# Routing in Php and decorator pattern

Tags: php, design-patterns, url-routing, decorator

I do not know if I am using the term 'routing' correctly, but here is the situation:

I created an `.htaccess` file to 'process' (dunno if my term is right) the url of my application, like this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I have this :

```
http://appname/controller/method/parameter
http://appname/$url[0]/$url[1]/$url[2]
```

What I did is:

1. setup a default controller, in case it is not specified in the url
2. setup a Controller wrapper

I did it like this

```
$target = new $url[0]()
$controller = new Controller($target)
```

The problem with that one is that I can't use the methods in the object I passed in the constructor of the Controller:

I resolved it like this :

```
class Controller {
  protected $target;
  protected $view;

  public function __construct($target, $view) {
    $this->target = $target;
    $this->view = $view;
  }

  public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    if (method_exists($this->target, $method)) {
        return call_user_func_array(array($this->target, $method), $arguments);
    }
  }
}
```

This is working fine, the problem occurs in the index where I did the routing, here it is

```
if(isset($url[2])){
    if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
         $controller->$url[1]($url[2])
    }
} else {
    if(method_exists($controller, $url[1])){
         $controller->$url[1]()
    }
}
```

where `$controller = new Controller($target)`

The problem is that the method doesn't exist, although I can use it directly without checking if method exist, how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please stop forcing routing mechanism into the controllers. You are violating [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle).

Comment: i replaced it.. i've realized it yesterday :D thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

As you've already discovered, you aren't able to use `method_exists` when it is being handled by a magic `__call` method. However, you can add an extra public method to your Controller to get around this problem:

```
class Controller {
  protected $target;
  protected $view;

  public function __construct($target, $view) {
    $this->target = $target;
    $this->view = $view;
  }

  public function hasMethod($method) {
    return is_callable(array($this->target, $method));
  }

  public function __call($method, $arguments) {
    if (!is_callable(array($this->target, $method))) {
        throw new \BadMethodCallException("Method `$method` is not callable");
    }

    return call_user_func_array(array($this->target, $method), $arguments);
  }
}
```

So...

```
if(isset($url[2])){
    if($controller->hasMethod($url[1])){
         $controller->$url[1]($url[2])
    }
} else {
    if($controller->hasMethod($url[1])){
         $controller->$url[1]()
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Changed `method_exists` to `is_callable` to ensure only public methods return true.

Answer (score 1):

Use `is_callable()` instead of `method_exists()` and it will return the correct result.

Comment: This is misleading - is_callable will ALWAYS return true when called on the decorator because of the magic `__call` fallback. It doesn't take into account what the outcome of this call is. The only way to get the desired result in this case is to ask the decorator if it's object has the method. Although it is probably better to use `is_callable` within this method though as `method_exists` will return true for protected/private methods, which wouldn't be callable.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: you are doing it wrong.  Now a bit longer one ...

The main issue here is that you are trying to shoehorn the routing mechanism in the controller. Controller in modern MVC patterns is responsible for taking information from user input, and apply it to model layer and/or current view to change their states.

It should **not** be responsible for extracting the information from raw input data. That should be done by some form of routing mechanism, which is used before your code actually *hits* the MVC triad. Preferably in bootstrap/initiation stage of your application.

Basically you do something like:

```
$uri = isset( $_GET['url'] ) ? $_GET['url'] : '/';
$request = new Request;
$request->setUrl( $url );

$router = new Router;
$router->route( $request );

$class = $request->getParameter('controller');
$method = $request->getParameter('action');

if ( !class_exists( $class ))
{
    $class  = 'ErrorController';
    $method = 'missingController';
}

if ( !is_callable( [$class, $method] ))
{
    $class  = 'ErrorController';
    $method = 'missingAction';
}

$controller = new $class( /* inject some dependencies */ );
$controller->{$method}( $request );
```

> <sub>This of course is simplified and somewhat clumsy example. **Do not copy-paste in production code.**</sub>

Comment: I wonder what does the `$router->route($request);` did? 
did it process the `$request`, then return it to the variable?

Comment: The `route()` method "prepare" the `Request` instance. In a real world implementation I would import possible routes in the `Router` instance, which would be turned into regular expressions. The `route()` method in that case would loop through all the expression till first match is found. In which case the data, that gets extracted from that regexp, is assigned to the `Request` instance. Basically the `route()` method prepares the `Request`.

Comment: I imagine that there would be `setUri` function and `getParameter` function in the `Request` class, and the `Router` class prepares the request, presumably , it sets the corresponding controller and action,.. so before the `request` calls the `getParameters` the `controller` and `action` has already been set, so I imagine that inside the `router` class, it sets a `req` array, e.g. `set->req('controller', $this->controller)`, like so?

Comment: Thing is, the `'controller'` parameters in the `Request` instance would be no more important then parameter named `'foobar'`. The router only extracts array of key-values pairs from the regular expression (using `(?P<name>pattern)` construction). What is the magical `req` array that you are talking about? You are making no bloody sense.